# error while accessing data from web api url using jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

While I am accessing the data from **Web API URL** using `Jquery Ajax` call, it returns an error :

> JavaScript critical error at line 1, column 10
>   incallback=jQuery17107603750517376723_1463978391325&query=a&_=1463978393499\n\nSCRIPT1004:
>   Expected ';'

Comment: may be missing semi colon some where

Comment: Update your `AJAX` call Snippet.